# Add title="" to A PHP Code

Tags: php

I am using a code to call WP thumbnails and want to add a title="" tag.  I would like the title to call the_title... how do I do so?  I want to assign the title tribute to the image, not the link.

My code:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'thmb-archive' ); } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the arguments available for `the_post_thumbnail(`) function as written in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail).

**Edit**: just did a test with this and it worked for me:

```
$post_title = the_title( '', '', false);//get the title
$attr = array('title' => $post_title);//set the parameter 
the_post_thumbnail('full', $attr);//call the function
```

Comment: Tried it, but I'm trying to assign the title attribute to the image, not the link.

Comment: Edited my answer, give a look and let me know.

Comment: I don't believe this works correctly, when done correctly it should assign the title to the image.

Comment: Yes, to the thumbnail actually, i just tested on a project i'm on with this exact function.

Comment: http://themeforward.com/demo2/templates/archive/
When no image is assigned a title is in place of the image.  However, the code above does not do the same.

Comment: Is it on a theme you're developing? I'd need to see more of the code at this point.

Comment: It is - which part of the code would you like to see?

How I would call it using your code, the title won't show up if there's no image...
<?php
$post_title = the_title( '', '', false);//get the title
$attr = array('title' => $post_title);//set the parameter 
the_post_thumbnail('thmb-archive', $attr);//call the function
?>

But just calling an image with title="" attribute added does bring up a title if nothing is given.  Check the link in my previous comment to see what I'm doing.

Comment: Pulling up most recent 20 posts using this...
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=20&paged='.$paged); 
 if (have_posts()) : 
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

Comment: I'd need to see the whole loop. Yes the title wont show up if there's no image, that'd be another option to set up. Use http://pastebin.com/ to paste your whole loop so i can give a look.

Comment: @Lucas Wynne - can you please clarify your question - what are you trying to achieve? your direct question has been answered: the thumbnail gets a title attribute, when you apply the suggested code; however - no thumbnail = no title attribute. do you want a textual spaceholder if the thumbnail does not exist? or a broken/empty image with a title attribute?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HREaTqkk Thanks for the help!